# Power cycling followed by monitor disconnect

Tags: windows-7, display, gateway

My computer intermittently power cycles , and will not interact with the monitor after the power cycle, forcing a hard shut down and start up sequence. It can be when the computer is idling or in full use. The one time I saw it happen, it spontaneously shut off, powered on for about 4 second shut off again,then showed power to the system, but the monitor never showed any indication that a computer was even attached. Where should I begin my troubleshooting?

System is a Gateway SXC 2851-41.

Comment: Have you tried an alternative wall plug?

Answer (score 1):

Possible issue with low voltage from mains. Slight brownout causes system to go down and sends devices like monitor into an unusual state.  Adding a UPS would help as it is difficult to constantly monitor voltage using normal tools like voltmeter or multi-meter.